# Rank of elliptic curves used in cryptography

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, cryptography

I was playing around with [an implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9f39a43e0d728721d5a9e2586ce47a57585591c5/src/crypto/elliptic/p256.go) of the NIST P-256 elliptic curve and I noticed that the field order and the order of the base point in the implementation are "close" :

Field order:
$115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951$

Group order:
$115792089210356248762697446949407573529996955224135760342422259061068512044369$

I see this as a consequence of Hasse theorem, and as an evidence that the base point is generating the whole group of the curve, which is then of rank 1.

Is it just a coincidence or is it something desirable for cryptographic purpose that the group of the underlying curve should have a rank equal to 1 ?

Comment: The OP meant cyclic instead of rank 1. For an elliptic curve over (a finite extension of) $\Bbb{Q}$ then $E(\Bbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}^r \times H$ where $H=E(\Bbb{Q})_{torsion}$ is a finite group, so it is often non-cyclic when it has rank $1$.

Comment: I actually meant the rank of the group being 1, which should be the same as this group being cyclic in the context of a finite group.

Comment: Crypto applications of elliptic curves work inside a cyclic subgroup of order that is a prime number. When the order is a prime, there are less ways to attack the underlying DLP. You can always simply pick a curve and a large prime factor of its order, but there seems to be a clear preference for curves such that we can use all of the curve rather than just a large subgroup. I guess this is because we can find such curves "easily" enough (I don't know the algorithms), so we might as well. Why use a 256-bit curve if you only get a key space and security of 254 bits :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cryptography we choose a curve $E$ over a finite field $K$ then the $E(K)$ is the groups of the points and $|E(K)|$ is the order of $E(K)$, i.e. cardinality, or the number of the rational points.

Then we choose a base point $G$, which is usually chosen as [nothing-in-my-slave number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing-up-my-sleeve_number) to prevent suspicious curve parameters. It is clear that the multiples of $[k]G$ ($\langle G\rangle$) form a subgroup of $E(K)$. Let call order of this subgroup $r = r = \left|\langle G\rangle\right|$ than by the Lagrange theorem
$$h = \frac{|E(K)|}{r}.$$ We call this $h$ as the **cofactor**

There is a small subgroup attack ([Lim–Lee active small-subgroup attacks](http://dasan.sejong.ac.kr/%7Echlim/english_pub.html) ).  The attacker chooses $P$ and the user reveals $[k]P$. The obvious method for the attacker is choosing $P$ in a small group where the ECDLP is easy.  If the curve $|E(K)|$ is prime then there are no non-trivial subgroups for the attacker. If near the prime like 8 in the Curve25519 the prevention is easy (see below).

We also want the $r$ to be prime to resist the Pohlig–Hellman algorithm.

**Does cofactor affect security?**

- It is clear that when the cofactor is 1 then $\langle G\rangle$ is the whole curve and any non-zero point can be a generator. Lim–Lee, and Pohlig-Hellman will fail.
- What if the cofactor >1? There is only some special need for checking that the incoming point is not on the small subgroup, rather than the $\langle G\rangle$. The designers of the curves take this into consideration, for example for Curve25519 has cofactor 8. When used with  Diffie-Hellman key exchange then while selecting the private key, the three least significant bit set to zero to guarantee that the private key in the $\langle G\rangle$

So $cofacor =1$ is easy to use. However, having larger some other advantages like the Montgomery Curves

- has the side-channel resistant Montgomery Ladder,
- every Montgomery Curve has a point of order 2 i.e. the cofactor is always >1.

---

**Note that**: the curve P-256 is suspicious since the coefficients generated by hashing the unexplained seed `c49d3608 86e70493 6a6678e1 139d26b7 819f7e90`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I know about "P-256 is suspicious", it appears only "suspicious" curves are shipped with built-in golang/crypto though...

Comment: Well, they only include the NIST P curves, nothing more, that is the reason.